# Is it possible to install Ubuntu on an external SSD on the 2019 16 inch MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, unix, t2

I'm considering buying the 16 inch 2019 MacBook Pro because I need a powerful x86 machine that can run macOS, but I would also be interested in running other operating systems on this computer. I know that the T2 chip is tied to the SSD, and I was wondering if the following configuration is possible, and how I would go along doing it:

- 2 partitions on the Apple SSD, one running Catalina, and one running Windows 10 through Bootcamp
- 1 external SSD with 2 partitions, one with Big Sur, and one with Ubuntu

If this is possible, how would I do this, and what problems would I face (WiFi, audio, etc)? If this isn't possible, what would I need to do to be able to run these 4 operating systems on this machine, or what other powerful x86 Macs would you recommend?

Edit: I don't want to run virtual machines because graphics performance is bad when the VM doesn't have access to the GPU, and graphics are one of the main reasons I would want to upgrade to the 16 inch. I also don't want to spend money on VMware and install it on my Bootcamp partition, just to find out GPU passthrough doesn't deliver the level of performance I would want.

Comment: Do you need to boot each OS from disk?  I would use VMs.  Your question seems to have already excluded that choice.

Comment: I would need to be able to boot these operating systems using the components inside the MBP as well as the external ssd. Preferably I would be able to install these with a USB. I don't like VMs because when I have tried them in the past I experience significantly lower performance.

Comment: Have  you consider using a Thunderbolt 3 drive? They are more expensive, but considerably faster than USB.

Comment: To boot the OS, I'm fine with using any type of external storage.